# Warning message "incomplete final line found by readTableHeader" when reading a csv using read.csv()

Tags: r

I am having trouble with loading this data file in R. Following code worked for the person giving tutorial while it doesn't work for me. The dataset is same as well.

```
spam.raw <- read.csv("spam.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fileEncoding = "UTF-16")
```

Getting following error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
invalid input found on input connection 'spam.csv'
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'spam.csv'
```

Comment: Either you have the encoding of the file wrong, or it's not a valid `.csv` format.

Comment: I have the data saved in csv formart only. I would check that again. Thanks for responding.